# can't make my unity character move

Tags: unity, c#, physics, blender, motion

so I'm starting with Unity , I followed the john lemon tutorial , and I wanted to apply what I learn on a model on my own coming from blender. 
Everythings works , animation , rotation , but not translation . For some reasons my character doesn't move at all . 
It might have to do something with root motion since I have apply root motion in grey with written just after "handled by script" . Not sure what to do .. 
I found something about character in place,  I think I'm in this case but I'm not sure how to use it in my script .. 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRootMotion.html

If you ask I'll give you my project .

EDIT :

ok so I made some advances :

```
 void OnAnimatorMove()
{
        m_Rigidbody.MovePosition(m_Rigidbody.position + m_Movement * m_Animator.deltaPosition.magnitude * 10000);
        m_Rigidbody.MoveRotation(m_Rotation);
        Debug.Log("m_Animator.deltaPosition.magnitude: " + m_Animator.deltaPosition.magnitude);

}
```

m_Animator.deltaPosition.magnitude is actually always equal to 0 , explaining why my charachter doesn't translate but why is it always equal to zero ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem, I started solving it by removing the last part:

`m_Animator.deltaPosition.magnitude` to some other float that i want and called it speed meaning my OnAnimatorMove is looking like this

//move the position

```
m_Rigidbody.MovePosition(m_Rigidbody.position + m_Movement * 0.05f);
```

you can either change the last float to a public variable for you'r convenient

Another sulotion that i found relevant to my case that in my animation setting of the walk animation i activated the ***bake into pos*** option for the x,z,y transforms once i disabled it that worked just fine with the same code
but i neede to add a speed variable and multiply by it because it was too slow

Answer (score 3):

> **Animator.deltaPosition** Gets the avatar delta position for the last evaluated frame.
>
> Animator.applyRootMotion must be enabled for deltaPosition to be calculated.
>
> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-deltaPosition.html

You have to enable your animator's `applyRootMotion`. if you don't enable this option or your avatar doesn't have a delta position (not changing position), then Animator.deltaPosition returns 0.

More about applyRootMotion:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-applyRootMotion.html

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution.

I ran into the same problem, but I solved it in the following way

1. animation correction
   I used my own models and animations, but I wasn't moving them forward despite the walking animation. (It was stamping feet on the spot.)
   This has been modified to move forward.
2. select the root node
   Armature/Hips were assigned to the Inspector/Rig/Root node of the model.
   Initially I was simply going to Armature, but then I realized that the root of the animation was Hips.

After fixing the above two points, the problem was solved.

I hope this helps those who still refer to this thread.

Sorry for the poor English, thank you.